# row.entity.xxxx property doensn't match after sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ng-grid

Ok so i have a problem.  I have a grid with about 5 columns. 
They are:
TaskQueryID, Comment1, Comment2, TaskID, ProjectName.

Data is loaded via WebAPI and everything is dandy.
Every cell in the grid runs off same template which turns the text in the cell into a link. The point of it is to the use that link to load more information about that row into the same grid.  This works as expected as well.

The problem i have is when i sort the columns.  During initial load, the data shows, i click lets say 3rd row link, i get correct detailed data.  I reload the page, try it again,  works fine.  THEN i repeat the test but after load i sort by random column (i tried all of them) and click said 3rd row link again and i get a problem.  Data shows up but not for the sorted 3rd row link but for the original load 3rd row link.
The underlying data is not sorted, just the UI?

I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  Turns out the parameters were referenced from the grid scope instead of the current click scope.  I'm just getting into Angular so this difference eluded me.   Hope this helps somebody!